# Get Google Map's Marker Content

Tags: google-maps

When I am adding a Google Map marker using [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#AddingOverlays) tutorial, I am able to add my own content into the body of the marker. Instead of adding my own content, I want to use the content that Google has stored about my business. I am wondering how would I be able to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to have Google populate the marker for you.  On my site I use the Google Places API to display info on the tooltip when a marker is clicked.

You can query the places API to using the Google reference number.  [Here's a direct link to the Google `PlaceDetailsRequest` section](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PlaceDetailsRequest).  Scroll down and you will see the `PlaceResult` object which gives you all the data Google has about that particular place.

If you just want to display the information for your business, you are better off statically putting the content into the marker.  Otherwise, if the data needs to be dynamic you need to pull it from somewhere yourself and Google Places is good if you don't have your own data.

Comment: I think you forgot to include the link in your response.

Comment: @icu222much Sorry about that, I fixed it.  It's pretty straightforward.  Everything you need starts at the link I gave you.  You just need the `PlaceDetailsRequest` object, an instance of `PlacesService` and that will get you a `PlaceResult` object that you can then use to fill out the marker content.